# Storing intermediate results during overridden equals method

Tags: java, oop, overriding, side-effects

Actual case:
I would like to override `public boolean equals(java.lang.Object obj)` for some of the objects in my current Java project. This method should still return `true` when the challenge object is considered equal to the current one. However, while establishing the equality between objects, I need to store some processing results in a data structure belonging to another, singleton, class (I have to store the list of differences if any, for future use in the application workflow).

Calling the overridden `equals()` will then have a side-effect which is intimately linked to the way I establish that the objects are equal. However, there is no side-effect to the method when it's not overridden. Is that considered as a design flaw? Is there any good practice that would go against such approach?

Oracle documentation about method overriding is quite laconic, imho, about this: "The ability of a subclass to override a method allows a class to inherit from a superclass whose behavior is "close enough" and then to modify behavior as needed.".

I don't see any restriction with such statement but I'd like to get advice from OOP developers/designers/architects.

Thank you!

More details (simplified code):

```
// Dataform is a JAX bean class
public class Dataform {
    String name;
    // Column is a JAX bean class
    ArrayList<Column> columns;
    // Footer is a JAX bean class
    Footer footer;

    // equals is redefined the same way for each JAX bean classes
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(this.getClass().isInstance( obj )){
            // equalsXML is a method that compares XML elements (JAX beans in this case). This method can in turn call equals() on 
            if (XMLObject.equalsXML( this, obj ).isEmpty()){
                // Store differences in singleton class for future access
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }
        else{
            return super.equals( obj );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give more description (i.e. code) around your "need to store some processing results"

Comment: *Caching* is not generally considered a side-effect, it is just a performance boost, by allowing the cached result to be queried faster on subsequent uses, whether from `equals()` or elsewhere.

Comment: If `equals` consistently returns as it should when called, and you aren't modifying the objects that you are comparing, there are no side-effects

Comment: I just edited the post, I actually need to store the differences discovered during the comparison, if any.

Comment: I would highly advise you not to do it. The `.equals()` method and business logic behind storing and processing these differences are so far away from each other... Are you sure that you really need to do it on each call of `.equals()`? Are you sure, that one of your colleagues (or you yourself) won't use `.equals()` in some place, where you don't need to process these differences and then won't spend hours of debugging trying to understand what went wrong in production. Either store difference explicitly at the places, where you want to do it or be a *risky guy* and use AOP.

Comment: Or at least write a custom method for comparison with side effect of storing difference. Just as an act of politeness to future maintainers.

Comment: Thank you Yaroslav. The `equals()` method for those JAX beans will be called only once with a specific argument, as designed in the application workflow. Afterwards, the equality information is stored in a data structure available throughout the whole application without requiring to re-check the objects (base, challenge). Assessing if two Dataform objects are equal is costly, I wanted to store this information (as well as the differences, if any) only once. I will also add a safeguard that will prevent from re-processing if the data structure has already been updated for the current object.

Comment: @A.Karali Oh, if it's only caching, than I agree with Andreas. It's normal to do so. But if there is any business logic behind it, than it's bad idea.

Comment: Your entire `equals` method is just `return getClass().isInstance(obj)? !XMLObject.equalsXML(this, obj).isEmpty(): super.equals(obj);`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do some extra processing for specific methods (or almost anything) whithout touching programs code, consider **Aspect Oriented Programming**. This is a technique when you modify bytecode either during compile time, or dynamically. It sounds complex, but its not. This technique is perfect for logging, monitoring, extra security, exceptions handling and many others. Personally I prefer to use it for things not related to domain model. Imagine if you need to do logging for entire program. You would need to add extra line to each method you want to log. With AOP you can do this with very few lines without touching your programs code at all. Read about **AspectJ**. It is oldest and probably most advanced tool so far (except BCEL - direct byte code manipulation framework)

Comment: Thank you Justas, I know about AOP but this wouldn't fit the specific case here. I need to store the list of differences (if any) between the two objects within a specific data structure, accessible from everywhere within the project (application).

Comment: @A.Karali I would be interested to know more about your code. Is the data you want to store is immutable? If yes, you can use a factory that creates objects and process that data for you. You can implement interfaces on these classes and use Decorator pattern for the ones you need. Or simply do that processing in overriden methods if you don't want to over-engineer your code. It is not so bad idea as long as you not violating SOLID.

Comment: The data is mutable since it has to be decided what to do with the stored differences (flag in the XMLDifference class): apply the difference to another Dataform or ignore it. I decided to go for such difference storage processing in the overridden equals and that's the point behind the question, is that something that would hurt one's good practices? Up to now, according to the previous comments, it doesn't seem so.